# Convincing colleague that playing to a metronome is a good thing?

Tags: practice, rhythm

I have a colleague that believes playing to a metronome is a bad thing as it ruins the "feel". While we agree that a strict metronome performance is generally boring and the tempo has to breath and we also agree that bad timing is bad. But he believes that in many cases the downbeats can sort of "move" depending what is played in between the beats in which case I generally disagree except when it is natural and intentional and it shouldn't be because of lack of technique.

Is there any nearly perfect reasoning that could convert someone who just sees it as somewhat a waste of time and/or just hard to do?

I know some are totally against the metronome and I find this mentality a bit like flat-earthers.  The metronome is a tool, use it like any other tool to get the job done(which is learning what steady time is/feels like).

Comment: Can you say anything about this colleague - can he read, is he still keen to learn new things, is he a serious music student etc. (Just trying to get a feel for whether he **can** be converted or even if it's worth bothering.)

Comment: What kind of group is this?  A jazz band vs. a rock band vs a string quartet vs. a synchronized K-pop dance troupe all have radically different requirements.  Further,  a pure metronome as opposed to a "click-track," which can simply synch all members to the source beat, is unlikely to be what you want in any performance.

Comment: Perfectly straight is a (particular) feel, and an essential one for a well rounded musician.

Comment: The hard-line argument is simply this: If you can play accurately *with* a metronome, you can then play whatever rhythmic feel you want *without* one. But if you can't play accurately, what "feels rhythmical" to you is quite likely to sound like "a chaotic mess" to everybody else. Of course once you *have* learned to "play straight", there is little value in using a metronome for *every* piece you learn in future. I rarely use mine for anything, except checking when the MM mark on a score looks implausibly fast or slow.

Comment: @Andy No, he can't read. He's mainly a blues player and believes feel is the most important thing. Unfortunately, his main problem is that he filters "feel" through his own senses. If it doesn't feel right to him(but others obviously do it, such as jazz), then it's bad or wrong.  He seems to be unwilling to believe that the reason many things feel wrong to him is because he is not good at it. E.g., the reason he struggles with the metronome is not because playing in time is bad but because he is not good at it and he doesn't like that feeling... and thinks it's due to the metronome and not him

Comment: @CarlWitthoft It is world music mainly. But regardless, I am mainly talking about timing independent of musical style. As I agree with Dave that it is more about being "well rounded".

Comment: @alephzero I basically agree, the problem is that he plays well with a drummer I think and does have a relatively good sense of time. But like everyone, it can be improved and we routinely record to a click track and there are very subtle timing issues. Sometimes he's dead on but other times he's off and it eventually causes the music to have some timing issues... they are probably not noticeable to the causal listener but I believe the best way to fix it is to practice to a metronome... even if he has great time otherwise.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't any perfect reasoning that can convert this player. He would probably improve with formal exercises, if he can be persuaded to do them. But many world music styles existed before the metronome, so he too can learn them "his way" (intuitively) with lots of practice and no metronome...

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different slant on this - why don't you practice with a metronome yourself - and then when you improve and your colleague asks "How on earth do you do that" you reply "Well actually..."

I often practice (trumpet) with a metronome ticking but I imagine the ticks are on the 'and' *between* beats rather than *on* the beat, so I mentally have to construct the unheard strong beats. This is good for rhythmic visualisation. You can also mentally push the tick around - imagine you're hearing a swing rhythm and the metronome ticks are on the second of each swung pair of quavers.

Also, I think people do mistake *tempo* for *feel*. Accomplished drummers (and other musicians!) know they can keep some hits (kick and high hats) right on the tick, but retard or push others (snare) to change the feel, whilst staying in tempo the whole time. Playing with a metronome lets you practice pushing hits around to change the feel, which improves the feel and makes you a better musician.

Comment: I do, I practice all the time(well, not all the time but)... It has helped me tremendously... While I have learned to play "in time" and to also feel the rhythm in the pulse of the metronome, which he has said is very hard for him. This tells me he just needs to practice to a metronome because it's specific feel creates uneasiness in him causing him to be off(it's not that he has bad timing, but more that the metronome "feel"(the simple clicks and pops") makes him uneasy. He can play to a drum track just fine, but that does obscure slight timing issues that the metronome makes obvious.

Answer (score 1):

It's going to depend to a great extent on what type or genre of music is being played. Dance music, of any era, will need to be 'metronomic', as dancers will rely on each beat being in the correct place - otherwise they'll have a tendency to fall over - or stop dancing. It's the same with marching music. However, there is a huge amount of music to be played that doesn't necessarily need to be bang on time. in fact a lot can sound better with that small change in tempo, an early or late beat, etc.

A lot of the early music - baroque, classical, et al, has a metronome mark that is approximate. So not set in stone, but purely as a guide. It's supposed to be subjective. So how does one set the metronme anyway?

There's a case for being able to play along with a metronome, starting and finishing with it, along with keeping together in the middle, but that's just a discipline worth practising, and doesn't necessarily make one a better player. There's also the case for being able to keep together with other players, and for this, a sense of rhythm is most important. BUT - it's also important to 'go with the flow', and having played with those who rely heavily on metronomes, and those who don't, I know which I'd rather be playing with.

So, playing Devil's advocate, is the metronome such a great tool anyway? Maybe it's a crutch, and we all know what happens when a crutch is taken away...

Comment: While I'm not a close friend of metronomes either, I consider them more as stabilizers. Learning how to ride a bicycle is much easier using them, and for me it's really hard work to move from a *inspired* to a *correct* rhythm, and even more so, after one gets used to the first one.

Comment: Please let me know which bit caused the downvote. I don't mind being downvoted, but it makes sense for the downvoter to give a reason, otherwise it's pretty pointless.

Comment: While I didn't downvote, I would summarize the answer as "devils advocate with some minor exceptions". This is obviously the contrary of what was asked for, since the mentioned colleague already has a negative attitude.

Comment: Well, you are saying things he would say more or less :) (I didn't DV)

Answer (score 1):

My argument for using a metronome- at least occasionally- is this: if you can't play a straight beat, you have no assurance that your "expressive" playing with the rhythm is not just bad technique.  You need to have a basis to start from, or it's all just sloppy.  Thus, I would say that it's at least worthwhile to use a metronome to check whether you can do a straight beat, and then you can do what you please with it.

Comment: I basically agree with this and have more or less expressed this to him.  I think playing to a metronome is a skill that allows you to, strictly with a metronome, improve your timing... but it generally translates to playing with others well, if they have good timing. My feeling is, that he simply has a misunderstanding of what a metronome is and does and this sets up a believe that it somehow will not help him and potentially will hurt him. (but he's not really dedicated to "improving" himself musically at this point for whatever reasons... and that is a big factor too).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to make absolutely categorical statements here - you are right that in most styles, the 'grooving' sections do usually have a steady pulse to the downbeat, but I wouldn't be surprised if some great grooves 'breathe' a little over the course of the bar. (I'm sure most grooves will follow the same pattern *from bar to bar* though, so you're right that it needs to be natural and intentional, not a question of 'randomisation'!)

Agreeing what feel you're actually aiming for might be a good first step. Listen to drum loops or performances that exhibit the kind of timing and feel that you want, and then play a click track alongside. Does the click track fit or not? If not, why not? It's sometimes instructive to open a piece in an audio editor or DAW and see where those beats *really* sit.

Even if there is a solid downbeat pulse, a simple metronome that just plays the downbeats might not always be the best thing to practice with - it may be that there's a kooky late 8th beat that you need to hit together, for example. In these cases a drum loop in the style you're aiming may be more useful.

Comment: My feeling on it is that having a very solid steady sense of pulse(a metronome sense) allows one to understand the irregularities better. Regardless, I think a metronome mainly provides a different thing than the rhythmic feel you are talking about.  A metronome allows one to "test" their accuracy and consistency. It is a "perfect" time keeper. Playing with other humans  requires playing in time but also "in rhythm". It is also a skill to have... and they complement each other. But like many things, only doing one or the other is limiting.